# Insert into Table by getting NextVal of Sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table called SEQ_TABLE which has two columns, SEQ_NAME and ID

```
SEQ_NAME        |  ID
----------------------
SEQ_TABLE_10    |   1
SEQ_TABLE_20    |   5
```

Where ID is the Max of COLUMN_1 of TABLE_10 and TABLE_20

Now, I have to Insert new records into TABLE_10 by obtaining **nextvalue** of sequence from **SEQ_TABLE**.

I have written PostgreSQL query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_10 (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) VALUES  ((SELECT nextval(SEQ_TABLE)),   'Bangalore' ,NULL);
```

When I execute above Query, It is giving below error:
********** Error **********

```
ERROR: column "SEQ_TABLE_10" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 99
```

But, following Query works fine in **MySQL** Database:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_TABLE(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) VALUES  ((SELECT nextval('TABLE_172_SEQ','true')),    'Bangalore' ,NULL);
```

What is the Exact Postgres Query to achieve it in **PostgreSQL** DB?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support sequence unlike Postgres. So this means that nextval function which you are using in MySQL might not be an inbuilt function from MySQL. Can you please check if you have any user defined function named as nextval in your MySQL database? If you get that function, you might just copy over the function to Postgres database and use it or else better go for creating sequence as mentioned in the answer by @apm

Comment: @Manish: MySQL its working fine.. Problem is with Postgres

Comment: You might have misunderstood my comment. I meant that MySQL doesn't have sequence and thus there is no chance of using nextval fuction in it. But you have a nextval function call being used in MySQL. I suspect the nextval fucntion which you are using in MySQL might be a user-defined function. Can you please check if you have any user-defined function named as "nextVal" in you MySQL database?

Comment: SELECT nextval('TABLE_172_SEQ','true') in your MySQL statement suggests that you have a user-defined nextval function which takes two parameters, the first being the table_name which is a column value in SEQ_TABLE.

Comment: @Manish: You are Right. and is there any way to get max value from column and increment it by 1. if column has no value, i m not getting 1 as a value.

Comment: You can surely increment it by 1 if the value is null just by comparing with IS NULL operator. But I don't think you might want this. For your case in order to migrate to Postgres, you might just want to use the same user-defined nextval function from MySQL in Postgres. Just copy the same function to Postgres and make any syntactical change if needed. Then the same call as MySQL should work in Postgres too

Comment: You might want post the user-defined nextval function from MySQL here for more help.

Comment: @Manish: True. can u give me the query needed to get value from column, and increment by 1. even if it is null?

Comment: Please try to do it on your own. It should be pretty straightforward. And if I help you in writing such an insanely simple query, the SO enthusiasts here will throw me out of this forum. The sole purpose of SO of helping people will get defeated if I do so. Please try writing on your own, and if you get any issues, post it. People are always there to help you with issues, but not with writing code

Answer (score 5):

You want to create a sequence, not a table(SEQ_TABLE)
Kindly refer this link
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html

*Eg.*

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 101;
SELECT nextval('serial');
create table MyTable(col1 int,col2 varchar(20));
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (nextval('serial'), 'nothing');
```

Answer (score 2):

In current PostgreSQL versions you would use identity columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table_10 (
   id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   other text NOT NULL
);
```

That will implicitly generate a sequence. You are not allowed to insert numbers into into `id`, but you have to

```
INSERT INTO table_10 (other) VALUES ('new');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_10 (id, other) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'new');
```

and `id` is automatically filled with the next value from the sequence.

---

On older PostgreSQL versions, you would use `serial` or `bigserial`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_10 (id serial PRIMARY KEY, other text NOT NULL);
```

Then `id` is of type `integer`, a sequence `table_10_id_seq` is created and a `nextval` call is added to the `DEFAULT` clause of the `id` column.

You can examine this with `\d` in `psql`:

```
\d table_10
                         Table "laurenz.table_10"
 Column |  Type   |                       Modifiers
--------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('table_10_id_seq'::regclass)
 other  | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "table_10_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Moreover, the sequence belongs to the table and will be dropped automatically when the table is dropped.

You insert rows omitting the `id` column like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_10 (other) VALUES ('something');
```

Then the `DEFAULT` values will be used.

If you want to do the same thing “on foot”, for example to use a different name or different starting values for the sequence, that would work like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_10 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, other text NOT NULL);
CREATE SEQUENCE table_10_id_seq OWNED BY table_10.id;
ALTER TABLE table_10 ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_10_id_seq');
```